# What exactly is a template T & parameter when instantiated with a string literal?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Sorry for asking a question which I think I know the answer to but it just seems so weird to me it can't be correct.

If I have a templated function

```
template<typename T>
int TemplatedSize(T &ref){
    return sizeof(ref);
}
```

and I instantiate it with a string literal like this:

```
int i = TemplatedSize("oh how I love C++ sometimes");
```

what I get stamped out by template instantiation would be a function taking a reference to an array of const char with a length of 28? I looked up the syntax for that and I must say I have never seen it in code before. Is this the equivalent of whats being instantiated?

```
int NonTemplatedSize(const char (&arrayRef)[28]){
    return sizeof(arrayRef);
}
```

If that is correct I would have to worry about code bloat if I had more than just a sizeof in my function body and called the function with many string literals of different sizes?

Comment: Yes. Yes. What bloat?

Comment: @Xeo if TemplatedSize had 20 lines of code in its body rather than just a sizeof and I used it with 100 different string literals all of different lengths then I would (barring optimization) have 100 different TemplatedSize functions in my binary ?

Comment: @PorkyBrain: Yes, you would have a different instantiation for each literal length used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is the right type, and yes you'll get a new instance for each length of string literal that you pass to it.  To help minimize bloat, you can make those functions inline, possibly passing a `char *`and a size to another non-template function.

```
int doSomeCalculation(const char *s,size_t n);

template <size_t n>
inline int doSomeCalculation(const char (&s)[n])
{
  return doSomeCalculation(s,n);
}
```

Comment: @PorkyBrain Note that while you cannot partially specialize a function template, you can provide a different base template that is more specialized and overload resolution will pick the *best* alternative.